# StepNavigationTemplate not working inside CreateUserWizard?

Tags: asp.net, templates, createuserwizard

I'm trying to set the StepNavigationTemplate, but it is not working

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server">
    <StepNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="Cancel" />
        <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="I Agree" />
    </StepNavigationTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Agree to Terms of Use">
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

It does nothing here, but when I put it inside an `<asp:WizardStep>` it works, but in that it adds the navigation buttons and the previous ones are still there, so it's not at all useful.  How is this supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean anything like this:

```
<WizardSteps>
<asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Your title" ID="wzsStep" StepType="Step"></asp:WizardStep >
.....
</WizardSteps>
<StepNavigationTemplate>

                        <asp:Button ID="uxPreviousStepBtn" Text="Previous" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                            Width="80" OnClick="uxPreviousStepBtn_Click" OnPreRender="uxPreviosStepBtn_PreRender" />

                        <asp:Button ID="uxNextStepBtn" Text="Next" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
                            Width="80" ValidationGroup="MainData" OnClick="uxNextStepBtn_Click" OnPreRender="uxNextStepBtn_PreRender" />


            </StepNavigationTemplate>

protected void uxPreviousStepBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Previous step will show
 myWizard.ActiveStepIndex =myWizard.ActiveStepIndex>0? myWizard.ActiveStepIndex-1:0;
}        
protected void uxNextStepBtn_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Check please if next step exists 
          myWizard.ActiveStepIndex =myWizard.ActiveStepIndex+1;
    }
```

Comment: for some reason my code sample was not showing up in my question.. but it is now. Do I need extra code/functions? I was under the impression simply having the template would be enough override the default step template (that's what the docs seem to imply)